# How to tell if a DXVA decoder has fallen back to software decoding

Tags: c#, c++, video, ms-media-foundation, dxva

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In the constraints, you read that "The maximum guaranteed resolution for DXVA acceleration is 1920 × 1088 pixels; at higher resolutions, decoding is done with DXVA, if it is supported by the underlying hardware, otherwise, decoding is done with software."

Is there a way to detect that decoding is done in software?

We have issues with AMD graphic controllers when attempting to decode 4K H264 video.

We know that the hardware doesn't support 4K decoding and in theory it should fall back to software.
However, we found that regardless of what it's supposed to do, we gets lots of corrupted or black frames.

I'm hoping that we could detect if DXVA has fallen back to SW decoding, in which case we don't attempt to use DXVA at all and use instead a full software path.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The H264 MFT doesn't expose whether it is using DXVA for decoding or not.

It uses `IDirectXVideoDecoderService::CreateVideoDecoder` to create DXVA decoders, so you can make a manual call to this function to see if it succeeds or not.

I added a full explanation (and apitrace log) for this in [Mozilla bug 1193547](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1193547#c1)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your application via mftrace (included in the Windows SDK)? The mftrace output is very verbose and will normally let you know which MFT is in use for the encoding. You may be able to spot a different MFT in use when the hardware encoding is available.

For example with H264 encoding the Intel MFT, which is a hardware encoder, will get used instead of the standard Microsoft one when the system hardware supports it.

Comment: You mean decoding ? I'm only interested in decoding

Comment: Sorry yes decoding. Although it doesn't matter since the mftrace output will spit out the MFT class ID it is using no matter what it's being used for, encoding, decoding, re-sampling etc. What you're interested in is the MFT class that gets used when the decoding topology is created.

Comment: But how can I use that information in my own code. I can't use mftrace obviously...

Comment: If you mean how can you determine which decoder MFT has been used by MF under the hood from within your own code I don't know. It is possible to construct your MF topology manually and specify exactly which decoder MFT to use but that could end up being fragile if the decoder is hardware specific.